# How do I positon inputed image file in kivymd

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I made a simple App that accepts image file input, but wherever an image is inputed it appears horizontally, rather than the original vertical position (what I mean is when an image is inputed it isn't as it normal is, it's orientation changes, I hope you understand.)

Please how do I fix this, so the orientation of the inputed image will be the same as the original orientation. I'd really appreciate your help.

Here's my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from plyer import filechooser

Window.size = (300, 530)

KV = """
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        id: progress_toolbar
        title: 'Progress'

    ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 2
            adaptive_height: True
            spacing: (10, 15)
            padding: [25, 25]

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'center'
                text: 'Before'

            MDLabel:
                halign: 'center'
                text: 'Now'

            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 120, 220
                elevation: 15
                radius: 8
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "camera-outline"
                    user_font_size: "24sp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    on_release: app.file_chooser1()
                Image:
                    id: img1
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                    # size_hint_y: .5

            MDCard:
                ripple_behavior: True
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 120, 220
                elevation: 15
                radius: 8
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: "camera-outline"
                    user_font_size: "24sp"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    on_release: app.file_chooser2()
                Image:
                    id: img2
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                    # size_hint_y: .5


            MDTextField:
                hint_text: 'Date'
                width: 100

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: 'Date'
                width: 100

"""


class Example(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def file_chooser1(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected1)

    def file_chooser2(self):
        filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected2)

    def selected1(self, selection1):
        self.root.ids.img1.source = selection1[0]

    def selected2(self, selection2):
        self.root.ids.img2.source = selection2[0]


Example().run()
```

Thanks a lot for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this:

from

```
MDCard:
    orientation: 'vertical'
```

to

```
MDCard:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
```

please share a screenshot for more help